The number of words that M doesn't accept is finite
I need to show that the following language isn't Turing recognizable:
$$\text{COFINITE}_{TM} = \{\langle M \rangle | M \text{ is a TM and } \overline{L(M)} \text{ is a finite language}\}$$
but I keep getting the situation where I have a finite set of words that M doesn't accept (either 0 or 1). What am I missing?

What were your attempts?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem

Note that a machine $T_{\emptyset}$ that recognizes the empty language is not in COFINITEtm, and so what Rice's theorem gives you is that COFINITEtm is not in coRE. However, the question asks about the converse: to show that the language is not in RE. In this sense, we need creative tricks, and I am not aware of a general known
way to tell.

You can define a reduction $f$ from $\overline{A_{TM}}$. The basic idea to let  $f$, upon reading an input $\langle M, w\rangle$, output $\langle T\rangle$, where $T$ is a TM that operates as follows.  Given  input $x$ of $T$:

$T$ computes $|x|$, and then
$T$ simulates the run of $M$ on $w$ for $|x|$ steps. If $M$ accepts $w$ during the simulation, $T$ rejects $x$; Otherwise, if $M$ did not accept $w$ during the simulation, then $T$ accepts $x$.

Now if $M$ does not accept $w$, then, in particular, it does not accept $w$ within $|x|$ steps for all $x$. Therefore,
$T$ accepts all inputs, and thus it recognizes a language whose complement is empty and thus finite.
Conversely, if $M$ accepts $w$ after exactly $t$ steps, then, by the definition of $T$'s operation, it holds that $T$ rejects all inputs $x$ with $|x| \geq t$. In particular, $T$ recognizes a finite language, and so $\overline{L(T)}$ is infinite.
What were you missing: the basic idea here is that we want to simulate the run of $M$ on $w$ and answer the opposite, but as $M$ may not halt on $w$, then $T$ may not halt as well. That's why we need to simulate the run of $M$ on $w$ while bounding the number of simulated steps. It is true that if we simulate for $< t$ steps, we won't reject when $M$ accepts $w$, but that happens only for finitely many inputs -- this is the reason why we simulate for $|x|$ steps, to guarantee that almost for every input, we would simulate a sufficient number of steps.

I don't understand why limiting the run to |x| steps will solve the problem. How and why did you choose this limit?

It solves the problem because of the second direction in the correctness. If $M$ accepts $w$, then it does so after a finite number of steps, denoted $t$. Then, if you consider the behaviour of $T$ on an input $x$, you find out that it behaves differently depending on whether $|x|\geq t$ or not. So my answer to your comment is to try to prove that the reduction works to get to the AHA moment. There is nothing too special about $|x|$ --  it just induces a way to partition inputs that $T$ rejects and accepts depending on the threshold $|x| \geq t$. So other functions of $|x|$ can work as well.
